# How to center div horizontally using flexbox model

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I'm using bootstrap and have problem with centering box in IE. Chrome works as expected.

Here is my markup:

```
<div class="modal modal-flex" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      IE, why I have so much problems with you?
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My `modal-flex` class is simple (I've removed vendor specific styles to simplify example):

```
.modal-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

In IE my box is moved right, in Chrome centered successfully.

IE:
[image]

Chrome[image]

Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vadimb/mj6ygckq/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add `flex-flow:column nowrap;` to align center in IE.

```css
.modal-flex {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow:column nowrap; /*Add this */
  justify-content: center;
  -ms-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal modal-flex" tabindex="-1" *ngIf="showAdding">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
  IE, why I have so much problems with you?
</div>
<!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks. To be honest - I found one more solution - not to use `justify-content: center;` style - it also starts positioning correct. So next solution also works: `display: flex; align-items: center;`. But anyway I will apply your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When one uses *frameworks*, they sometimes combine properties in a way that not always work properly when you, in this case, add a new standard, and especially Flexbox, which can give you very unpredictable results.

In this case, a media query sets auto-margin to the `modal-dialog`, which IE doesn't like.

Assuming you want to use flex row direction, and align the dialog both horizontal and vertical, add this CSS rule

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .modal-dialog {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mj6ygckq/6/)

Answer (score 0):

I found also simpler solution - exclude `justify-content: center;` style rule. And positioning started working as well

```
.modal-flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Here is updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mj6ygckq/8/

Comment: By only remove `justify-content: center;`, it will not center the dialog horizontally on smaller screens

Comment: No, it centered. Remove this style `flex-flow:column nowrap;` from your fiddle (use css from answer only).

Comment: You demo works because you use `flex-flow:column nowrap;`, so try without in IE, and resize, and you'll see what happens

Comment: After your edit, try that fiddle in IE, and size the width small, and you'll see it doesn't center it horizontally

Comment: The proper way to solve issues like this, is to find the real reason, and fix that. Any other trick will likely bite back sooner or later. I really recommend you check my answer

Comment: It centered fine in my case for screens more-or-equal media width. You can check by resizing demo view. I think centering not working for screen less than media because of bootstrap media rule. So this file in my case also.

Comment: My answer properly solve this, explains why/what to look for and center the dialog in any screen size, both vertical and horizontal, but you can of course use any other solution, just be aware of that some can back-fire later.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will try to work with all proposed solutions to get some feedback from customers first.